# Delonghi Specialista not brewing anymore

Tags: coffee-machines

The filter of my Delonghi Specialista coffee machine was clogged when I used it last and the machine stopped working since. The gauge went in the red when it happened and then dropped suddenly.

The state of the machine:

- Doesn't get hot and therefore no brewing or steamer working.
  You can however get cold water out from the "tap".
- After cracking the machine open I can confirm the boiler isn't getting hot and no water is getting there.
  The relay supposed to feed the water comes on and off with the pump running, but it eventually gives up.
- The heating elements of the boiler and steamer seemed to have a reasonable resistance in open circuits, but I could not disconnect the sensors to check them that day.
- No leak observed.
- I tested the pressure gauge that seems fine.

Any advice would be welcome.